# Shared IndexedDB store between different web browsers

Tags: javascript, dart, browser, indexeddb

Using Dart lang, I've generated an application that stores several list of objects. I'm very happy with the result, congrats to Dart Team, but I have a question:

If I store several data using Chrome, is there any way to read this info from other web browser, i.e. Firefox.

That's why the user works with several web browsers in the same machine, he/she doesn't care which browser is open at that time, he/she wants to use the application in the current opened web browser.

[image: 2 web browsers running in same host connected to the same local indexedDB]

Comment: IMHO the only way would be if you have some syncing to a external server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers can't access each other's data directly,  but, given your diagram, it looks like IndexedDB is on the shared server and not in the particular browser so I can't see the problem.

If you have your database running on local server and it is accessible only with Dartium and for some reason you don't want or can't compile the browser part to JS(with dart2js) or do something else to make it accessible from the browsers without DartVM. then  I can think of 3 ways how to perform browser to browser data transfer without the server(on which application is hosted):

1. With [HTML5 Drag and Drop](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) between browser windows.
2. Creating [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) client\server and transferring the data this way.
3. Using remote server and simple authentication with Gmail,Facebook etc. **[the reasonable way]**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, "Browsers can't access each other's data directly", it is what I need to know. I meant 2 web browsers running in the same host, both sharing the same local indexedDB.